# Send payment amount to POS card payment terminal

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, point-of-sale

We do have a web based billing system in our pharmacy and we use Chrome to access the system. Currently we are expecting to integrate our POS card payment machines to the billing points as it will reduce the wait time of the customer at the counter.

So my case is,

Connect the POS machine with USB connection and use Web Serial API to send the payment amount to the POS machine, so the cashiers need not to type the amount.

We are not expecting any other option like reading card information as we are not authorized for it. So basically it will be a one way communication, send the amount to the POS machine, so the customer can tap his card on it.

How can I achieve this? I think I can do it with Javascript alone without any other native application.

Will we have to change the system when we change the POS machines or the banking partner?

Do we any help from the bank on this?